# Have all Routes use basename subdirectory, except for one Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My react app is being integrated into an already exisiting Maven Project and needs to have a sub directory of `/my`.

So all the `Route`'s need to have the `basename` of `/my/~~~`. However, there is one route that does not requires the sub directory, and if applied, hitting that route is causing an infinite loop.

The particular route is `/logout`. So hitting `/my/logout` causes the infinite loop.

There is only one reference in the project that links to the `logout` Route and that a `Link`

```
<Link to={"/logout"}>Logout</Link>
```

Below is my `App.js` with my `<Router>`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename="/my/">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path={"/"} component={Login} />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route
            path="/website-user/reset-password/:token/:userId"
            component={ResetPassword}
          />
          <Route
            path="/complete-registration/:token/:userId"
            component={FinishRegistration}
          />
          <Route path={"/register"} component={Login} />
          <Route
            path="/register?email=:email&telephone=:telephone"
            component={Login}
          />
          <Route path={"/"} component={SubNav} />
        </Switch>
        <Route path={"/overview"} component={Overview} />
        <Route path={"/favourites"} component={Favourites} />
        {/* How to get LogoutComponent to go to /logout instead of /my/logout */}
        <Route path={"/logout"} component={Logout} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So it possible to have all `<Route>`'s go to `/my/~~~` except for LogOut to go to `/logout`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** You cannot do this.

You shouldn't have multiple `BrowserRouters` on the page.

That won't work regardless, as it's talking to the nearest Router ancestor. Once you wrap another Router, you've created a new history instance and therefore a whole subset of routes and links.

Just a workaround is, don't create `route` for `logout`, instead handle your `logout` functionality using `onClick` function in the same component where you have your `logout` button.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, couldn't see anything in the Docs for any workaround